# How can I update the query params from within an iFrame in React?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, query-string

I am using the library `use-query-params` in react to set the query params when filters change like:

```
const [query, setQuery] = useQueryParams(queryParamConfigs, {
    removeDefaultsFromUrl: true,
});

useEffect(() => {
    setQuery(appliedFilters)
}, [ appliedFilters ])
```

but this won't update the query params in the parent iFrame. Do I need to somehow post a message to the parent and then use that message on the parent application to update the query params there? I control both the parent and the child applications.

Comment: Can you add the code which holds the logic? ie. the parent iframe.